# JInternalFrame Issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8, jinternalframe

I could not use `JInternalFrameForm` in Netbeans.

I did right click on my package and go new but I did not see JInternalFrameForm option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right click New menu only shows you options you have commonly used, or only several default options if you haven't used any.

to find JInternalFrameFrom, select the `Other` Option on the bottom of the options,

Then type in `JInternalFrame` in the search box of manually find the component inside the `Swing GUI Form` folder.

see the image below
[image: how to find JInternalFrame Form]